# By how much does Foundation scale its text?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, typography

Foundation scales h1-h6 at min-width: 40em. I am overriding Foundation's default h1 font-size. I set my h1 to font-size: 1.4rem. I am trying to figure out how to scale it on min-width: 40em in proportion to Foundations scaling. I think my h1 should be around 2.9rem

**This is the default font-sizes that Foundation defined**

h1 1.5rem

h2 1.25rem

h3 1.1875rem

h4 1.125rem

h5 1.0625rem

h6 1rem

**This is the font-sizes Foundation defined at min-width: 40em**

```
@media print, screen and (min-width: 40em) {
h1 {
  font-size: 3rem; }
h2 {
  font-size: 2.5rem; }
h3 {
  font-size: 1.9375rem; }
h4 {
  font-size: 1.5625rem; }
h5 {
  font-size: 1.25rem; }
h6 {
  font-size: 1rem; } }
```

Comment: Well, divide the 2 values and you get the factor to calculate yours, and for `h4` it is 1.5625 / 1.125 = 1.38889

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to alter Foundation Header Font Size is to open your **_settings.scss** file and, under "4. Base Typography", edit these lines :

```css
$header-styles: (
  small: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 24),
    'h2': ('font-size': 20),
    'h3': ('font-size': 19),
    'h4': ('font-size': 18),
    'h5': ('font-size': 17),
    'h6': ('font-size': 16),
  ),
  medium: (
    'h1': ('font-size': 48),
    'h2': ('font-size': 40),
    'h3': ('font-size': 31),
    'h4': ('font-size': 25),
    'h5': ('font-size': 20),
    'h6': ('font-size': 16),
  ),
);
```

Then recompile your CSS by running GULP "Foundation Watch".

Comment: This assumes the OP is using SASS. This won't work with the pre-compiled CSS version of Foundation.